# How to integrate google analytics for calculate visitor to my specific item

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-analytics

i am developing an ecommerce site. i want to calculate how many time my item viewed, calculate new visitors, total visitors number of click to purchase. And detail of visitor.
i have read documentation of google analytics and have search on many sites. but there is no easier and step by step guide available to calculate these things kindly guide me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Analytics offers a feature called "event tracking". You can use this feature to track clicks on specific HTML Dom Elements (Buttons, Links, Images etc.) and generate analytics data for your website.

Read more about [GA Event Tracking](https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6106716)